# Creating multiple read-only properties dynamically in AS3

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, private, dynamically-generated

I have a class which at the moment is quite messy/repetitive:

```
public class AvFramework extends Object
{
    // vars
    private var _handler:AvHandler;
    private var _keyboard:AvKeyboard;
    private var _manager:AvManager;

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function AvFramework()
    {
        _handler = new AvHandler();
        _keyboard = new AvKeyboard();
        _manager = new AvManager();

        // attach
        _handler.framework = this;
        _keyboard.framework = this;
        _manager.framework = this;
    }

    /**
     * Getters
     */
    public function get keyboard():AvKeyboard{ return _keyboard; }
    public function get manager():AvManager{ return _manager; }
}
```

This class is only going to need to make use of more and more classes, and I don't really want to have 3 huge lists for this like above.

Is there a way to do the above dynamically - maybe using `getDefinitonByName()` in a loop of strings to represent the classes I want to create.

I also want the properties to be read-only and to be accessed via `framework.myDynamicVarHere`.

I'm thinking something along these lines:

1. I create a list of the classes I want to create instances of, paired with the variable name they should be accessed by.
2. I will need to make the class `dynamic` so that I can set the vars via `this["var"] = new Blah();`

Quick snippet of where my thoughts are going:

```
var required:Object =
{
    keyboard: "avian.framework.background.AvKeyboard",
    manager: "avian.framework.background.AvManager",
    handler: "avian.framework.background.AvHandler"
};

var i:String;
for(i in required)
{
    var Req:Class = Class(getDefinitionByName(required[i]));

    this[i] = new Req();
    AvFrameworkObject(this[i]).framework = this;
}
```

Just not sure how I would be able to make these read-only.

Comment: this: `var i:String;for(i in required)` isn't necessary. With `for(var i:String in required)` you only initialize the String once and the string persists after the for loop. The only thing the additional line gets you is... an additional line.

Comment: @cwallenpoole True, this simply reads nicer to me. @Eugeny89 Thanks :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use Proxy class to control get/set call and complete Eugeny89 answer.
Look at http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/Proxy.html or http://blog.joa-ebert.com/2007/05/25/as3-proxy-example/

```
var required:Object =
{
    keyboard: "avian.framework.background.AvKeyboard",
    manager: "avian.framework.background.AvManager",
    handler: "avian.framework.background.AvHandler"
};
...

import flash.utils.Proxy;
import flash.utils.flash_proxy;
public dynamic class AvFramework extends Proxy { 
    private var holder: Object = {};

    public function AvFramework() {
        var i:String;
        for(i in required)
        {
            var Req:Class = Class(getDefinitionByName(required[i]));
            var name = //get Class name from required[i] e.g. AvKeyboard from avian.framework.background.AvKeyboard
            holder[name] = new Req();
            holder[name].framework = this;
        }
    }

    flash_proxy override function getProperty( name: * ): *
    {
        return holder[name];
    }

    flash_proxy function setProperty(name:*, value:*):void
    {
        // Do nothing
    }
}
```

With this code, when you do myAvFrameworkObj.something, getProperty() is automaticaly call and you get property name from "name" variable.

Comment: You should have private var holder: Object = {}; (and not initialize it new Object in the constructor) if you want to follow Adobe stylistic standards.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you'll try to wrap that long list of classws in object:

```
var required:Object =
{
    keyboard: "avian.framework.background.AvKeyboard",
    manager: "avian.framework.background.AvManager",
    handler: "avian.framework.background.AvHandler"
};
...

public class AvFramework extends Object { 
    private var holder: Object;

    public function AvFramework() {
        holder = new Object();

        var i:String;
        for(i in required)
        {
            var Req:Class = Class(getDefinitionByName(required[i]));
            var name = //get Class name from required[i] e.g. AvKeyboard from avian.framework.background.AvKeyboard
            holder[name] = new Req();
            holder[name].framework = this;
        }
    }

    public var getHolder() { return holder; }
}
```

You can refer to e.g. `AvKeyboard` by `framework.getHolder()["AvKeyboard"]` or even by `framework.getHolder()[someVar]`. So all this classes from `required` are read-only, as `holder` is read-only.

Hope that'll help you!

Comment: Nice answer - I had the same thought, however accessing everything (from a framework object) via framework.getHolder()["things"] over framework.things is extremely off-putting :(