# AS3: Overriding Proxy getProperty method

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, proxy, getter-setter

I've run into a peculiar problem while trying to make use of the `Proxy` class and override the `getProperty()` method. I've attached my example class code below:

```
package
{
    import flash.utils.Proxy;
    import flash.utils.flash_proxy;

    public class Thing extends Proxy
    {
        // holder object
        private var _holder:Object;

        /**
         * Constructor
         */
        public function Thing()
        {
            _holder =
            {
                stuff: "thing"
            };
        }

        /**
         * Override getProperty
         */
        override flash_proxy function getProperty(name:*):*
        {
            trace(name + " being accessed");
            return _holder[name];
        }
    }
}
```

I've been trying to use this to make some properties read-only (as per an answer on a [previous question of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6222713/creating-multiple-read-only-properties-dynamically-in-as3)), however there's some odd behaviour that I can't seem to work out.

Using the above, I try and access the variable `stuff` like so:

```
var t:Thing = new Thing();
trace(t.stuff);
```

However this throws the following error:

> **1119:** Access of possibly undefined property stuff through a reference
>   with static type Thing.

But if I do this:

```
trace(t["stuff"]);
```

It works fine. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because your class isn't dynamic, just add "dynamic" keyword and all will be good :

```
public dynamic class Thing extends Proxy
```